# why MVC and singleton both are 'design pattern'?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Every literature that is searched said that "MVC - is a design pattern assigns..." and the same such pattern as Singleton describes as "a software design pattern".

But WHY? These are different things that specify concepts on different levels of developing. In one MVC project you can have few Singleton, Factory and Unit of Work for example. But MVC and all these patterns still will be called 'design patterns'.

Comment: MVC is a design pattern because 1) it fits the definition of a design pattern, and 2) because it is recognized as a design pattern.  I don't really understand the basis for your questioning it.

Comment: There are multiple design patterns in several classifications then can be used together as needed. So I do not get the question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list. Lets try to ask it the other way around: why can't MVC and singleton not be both design patterns. What would be your answer?

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192887

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were confused here with architectural and design pattern. In this case, both are different.

MVC is an architectural pattern where as Single-ton is an design pattern.

**Design patterns** - are for solving some common technical problems which are addressed using OOPs concepts.
Example: How to write a code to have a single object for a single user rather than creating many such objects which results in lack of memory.

**Architectural Patters** - are for solving software application architecture problems which mostly addresses scalability, reliability, security, etc.,.
Example: How easily we can handle an application if its size gets increased ?

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is where I got misunderstanding